# Sharepoint Document Library Template Mandatory fields

Tags: 2013, content-type, template

I have a Sharepoint 2013 document library that uses a custom content type that has some mandatory fields (ie department, revision number).  I have created a word template file to use as the content type template.  However I can't save the template file without putting data in those mandatory fields.

Is there a way to save a content type template that does not have the mandatory fields filled in.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, instead of saving the template directly into SharePoint, save it locally to your computer, and then in Content Type | Advanced Settings choose 'Upload a new document template', and the mandatory fields can be empty.